# How to restore samba config?

Tags: retropie, samba

I edited my `/etc/samba/smb.conf` file, and now my samba share is not accessible and the the `/var/log/samba/log.smbd` is reporting a non-useful mkdir error. I have removed the changes I thought I made, but that did not help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To restore a samba config to the original, I did the following:

- Download the [image](https://retropie.org.uk/download/).
- Extract the image.
- Clone the image on to a flash drive: `sudo dd bs=4M if=retropie-4.3-rpi2_rpi3.img of=/dev/sdb conv=fsync`
- Copy the file on the flashdrive to the Pi: `scp .../etc/samba/smb.conf pi@192.168.0.1:/tmp/`
- On the pi: `sudo mv /tmp/smb.conf /etc/samba/`

Comment: Or, `sudo apt-get install --reinstall samba samba-common-bin` ?

Comment: Please accept your own answer with a click on the tick on its left side. Only this will finish the question and it will not pop up again year for year.

Comment: @Ingo At the time I wasn't sure if this was the best way to do it, so I never accepted my answer. Since no one else has answered, I guess I will accept it.